# Sharing ibm notes data with other websites

Tags: sql-server, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, ibm-domino

At our company we have a custom made ERP built with ibm Domino. Next to this we also have a webshop built with PHP. Currently we are sharing each others data. In Domino I have done this by creating java agents which receive and send data, this happens on the main server and a replicate server. The problem is that there are getting more and more agents. I was thinking about a way how to do this different. Instead of agents I was thinking about setting up a SQL Server in which I will store the Notes documents data. This SQL Server can then be shared with the website. Is this possible? Or are there better ways to fix this?

Comment: Domino and Notes *are* databases in the sense you mean. The *can* handle a lot of clients and agents. After all, they are used for document management and collaboration for the largest enterprises for decades.  If you have performance problems you'll have to be specific, explain what the problem is and post your code

Comment: If you get concurrency issues it means you aren't using the API correctly. You won't fix that by copying out the data. Domino is a *document management system*. If *one* persons opens a document for editing, others may read the original if versioning is enabled but they can't write over the other guy's edits. It's no different than Git or Subversion

Comment: Use versioning and checkout/checkin properly. If you don't intent to read a document, open a read-only copy (if possible). If you *do* want to edit a document, make sure you check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of synching Notes data to SQL Server and having PHP access the SQL data, why not just code your PHP to directly access the Notes data using [Domino Access Services](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp%3FlookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1)?

Answer (score 0):

One option is DECS virtual fields.  The Notes document is a stub which contains a key field (and optionally other information as well.)  DECS uses the key field to look up the record in an external database (such as SQL or DB2) and pull the data real-time into Notes.  To the Notes user, it looks like the data is stored in Notes but it's actually in the external database.
[Documentation about DECS Virtual Fields] http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/decs/6.0.1a/decsdoc6.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/7b7c3bc1e2ab5c1a05256ca9006fa5a8?OpenDocument